# How to perform efficient SELECT * queries in C* (Cassandra)

Tags: database, performance, cassandra, architecture, nosql

With a lot of data in a table the SELECT * queries seem to be inefficient.
How is it possible to solve this problem?

Are there any ideas for a design of C* infrastructure or a design of table itself?

Might there be any special query structure to perform select all elements more efficient?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> With a lot of data in a table the SELECT * queries seem to be inefficient.  How is it possible to solve this problem?

With a relational database, SELECT * FROM without restriction == **full table scan**

With a distributed database like **Cassandra**, SELECT * FROM without restriction == **full CLUSTER scan**, possibly on a cluster of 100+ machines ....

Long story short, it is **not designed** for full table scan.

If you need to scan through all the data from a table, use **Apache Spark** with the **Spark/Cassandra** connector to do the job.

> Might there be any special query structure to perform select all elements more efficient?

No, magic doesn't exist. And if someone ever finds a way to perform full table scan in distributed database extremely fast, he'll be millionaire already.

Comment: Plus one for: "if someone ever finds a way to perform full table scan in distributed database extremely fast, he'll be millionaire already."